# Does Street View has any cost? Can I use it on Windows Phone systems?

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-7, licensing, google-street-view

I want to develop an application for Android, Ios and Windows Phone. This application uses in huge way street view / augmented reality..

So my questions are:

- Use Street View in my app has any cost or is it free to use?
- Is possible to use it on Windows Phone / IOS?

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. [Why we're not customer support for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible

For Android : its free of cost , you only need to use Map Api(register by email)

For IOS : I dont think you need extra cost for using api, procedure might be different
                      http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MapKit_Framework_Reference/_index.html

For WINDOWS phone 7 http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.in/2010/10/google-maps-for-windows-phone-7.html

accept answer kindly if it is helpful any problem , please tell me

Answer (score 1):

In Windows Phone 7 you are free to use Bing Maps but you must first have a developer account at bing :) and that's very easy. This link will guide you to how to get bing map key and it is for free [Getting a Bing Maps Key](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff428642.aspx)

In Android Google Maps will achieve the Job but in IOS I don't know :)
This is a link will help you using google maps and how to get the key
[Android Google Maps tutorial](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/02/android-google-maps-tutorial.html)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware  that according to the Bing Developers' blog, MS is going to start charging to use the Bing Search API soon: http://www.bing.com/community/site_blogs/b/developer/archive/2012/04/12/bing-dev-update.aspx